# Unexpected result Python: np.power(a,3)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm evaluating this simple python code

```
a = np.array([6700,6728,26600,26600,42160], dtype=int)
a = a * 1000

print(a**3)

>> [ 5615094820647174144 -9045108901062377472  5417044816257351680
  5417044816257351680  7275268591801335808]
```

Same result with `np.power(a,3)`

Nevertheless, If I define the array as dtype=float

```
a = np.array([6700,6728,26600,26600,42160], dtype=float)
a = a * 1000
print(a**3)
```

The result is correct:

```
[3.00763000e+20 3.04549540e+20 1.88210960e+22 1.88210960e+22
 7.49379497e+22]
```

And I don't understand the difference in the result.

Comment: We get spoiled by Python, which has unlimited precision integers.  Numpy doesn't do that, because the code is all in C and Fortran, not Python.  When you ask for an `int`, your elements will be 64-bit integers.  They do not grow, and you are overflowing that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed, we get spoiled by Python. Now, it is clear for me.

Comment: @TimRoberts: For that matter, the floating point results are going to be slightly wrong, because `float`s can't represent every integer beyond a certain bound; the results are roughly the right order of magnitude, but still wrong (`((6700 * 1000) ** 3) == ((6700. * 1000) ** 3)` is `False`, the `float` has an off-by-32768 error).

Answer (score 1):

You're overflowing the integers

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors